# How can I prevent a CSS class selector from taking effect if another class is present?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a code where if class `x` is present, class `y` is disabled. I'm just a little lost on how to do it. I tried a bit of jQuery, but it didn't work.

This is what I've tried:

##### The script:

```js
if (element.classList.contains('img-1')) {
    element.classList.remove('ani');
}
```

##### The CSS:

```
.ani {
     width: 120px;
     height: 120px;
     background: red;
}
.img-1 {
     width: 120px;
     height: 120px;
}
```

##### The HTML:

```html
<div class="ani"></div> 
<img src="" class="img-1">
```

I was expecting the `.ani` class to disappear when the `.img-1` class is present. So if an `.ani` div appeared on it's own without the `.img-1` class, it would be visible, but the moment the `.img-1` class appears, I was expecting the *`.ani`* class to disappear.

Comment: As I asked in your previous question, how are you running the JavaScript? It won't re-execute the condition every time the class changes. You need to put it in a function that you call whenever you change the class of the element.

Comment: You could use a `MutationObserver` that runs whenever the element is changed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener

Comment: I'm running the script through codepen? And I don't think I follow the parameters of the mutationobserver, can you please show me an example? @Barmar

Comment: The word "invisible" in your question title implies that you want all elements with the `ani` class to be _visibly hidden_ on the page when a `img-1` class is present in the DOM. But the inclusion of that JavaScript where you're _removing_ the `ani` class from elements implies you don't want those elements hidden at all, and you just want to remove that class. Which is it?

Comment: There's an example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: Maybe you want to check the example on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom. How will the element `<div class="ani"></div>` be generated exactly?

Comment: I tried it here:

https://codepen.io/tanaproma/pen/qBvxpLQ?editors=1010

But it still seems to be glitching?

Comment: "glitching" is not really a technical term we can work with.

Comment: glitching meaning that it doesn't really change the outcome at all.

Comment: Do you _really_ mean to have the class removed or do you just need it to ignore the rules from the `.ani` class if `.img-1` is present? That would be achievable without any JavaScript.

Comment: YES! Ignore the rules of .ani if IMG-1 is present!!! @gyohza

Comment: If you could show me how to do that, it will be perfect. I just had a very hard time explaining it in english. THANK you!!! @gyohza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I took into account **the very question** you were asking (a class that would prevent another class from taking effect). The answer from @jla doesn't go that way and proposes further changes to the CSS. If your scenario applies, I agree that you should consider applying their changes to your code - but I'm gonna leave this here either way to answer the question at hand.

---

As per your requirements, you could achieve your objective by appending the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) CSS pseudo-class to the `.ani` selector:

```css
.ani:not(.img-1) {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: red;
}

.img-1 {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ani"> Hi, I'm <code>.ani</code> </div>
<div class="ani img-1"> I'm <code>.ani</code>, too, but ain't red </div>
<h1 class="ani"> Yay, I'm <code>.ani</code> and red, too </h1>
<div class="img-1"> Eh, I am neither </div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/120/120" class="img-1" title="I'm just an image" />
```

By appending `:not(.img-1)`, it will only ever select an element that does **not** match `.img-1` - so any element bearing the class will not be affected.

---

By the way, just for the sake of clarity - your JavaScript approach would work if you were to fix a few things:

```js
// select every .ani element which also has a .img-1 class
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.ani.img-1');

// loop through all the elements
for (const element of elements) {
  // remove class from each element inside elements
  element.classList.remove('ani');
}
```

```css
.ani {
     width: 120px;
     height: 120px;
     background: red;
}
.img-1 {
     width: 120px;
     height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ani"> <code>ani</code> </div>
<div class="ani img-1"> <code>ani</code> + <code>img-1</code> </div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/120/120" class="img-1 ani" title="img-1 + ani">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/120/120" class="img-1" title="img-1">
```

Maybe you didn't share the whole code, but the way it was, `element` was not an existing variable and therefore couldn't have anything in it. In my above snippet, I created an `elements` variable, then selected every element that had both `.ani` and `.img-1` classes.

Then it was just a matter of [looping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) through each of the elements and then applying `.classList.remove('.ani')` to each of them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using JavaScript to remove classes is an over-engineered solution for you situation. It would be better to use CSS specificity and overrides, as this is exactly the intent of CSS.

In CSS, the more *specific* the rule's selector is, the higher priority it is given. If there are two CSS rules that target the same element, one giving it a background of red, and the other a transparent background, the CSS rule with the most specific selector will be used.

For example, a CSS rule that sets the background red might look like:

```css
.ani {
     width: 120px;
     height: 120px;
     background-color: red;
}
```

We could make a second rule that is more specific like so:

```css
.ani.img-1 {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

In CSS when you see two classnames together with no space, it means "target elements that have both of the classnames". A selector with two classnames is more specific that a selector with one. So in the above example, if there was an element `<img src="" class="ani img-1">`, the CSS rules with selector `.ani.img-1` would override the corresponding rules with selector `.ani`, and the background would be transparent.

Note that there are no `width` or `height` rules in `.ani.img-1`. Because the example `<img ...>` element has the class `ani`, all of the rules in `.ani` that are not overridden by `.ani.img-1` will still be applied to it.

You can test the code in the snippet below. For easier viewing `.ani.img-1` has been given a blue background rather than transparent.

```css
.ani {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background-color: red;
}
.ani.img-1 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="ani"></div>

<div class="ani img-1"></div>
```

For in-depth information on CSS specificity, see [the MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).